# Game not ending in python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to make connect 4 with pygame and everything is working fine except for the end condition. I have a variable called `winner` which is always equal to `None`, `y`, `r`, or `draw` depending on the state of the game. I also have a function in another file called checkWin that returns one of the values for `winner` given the current position. I also have a function called `getWinner` that sets `winner = rules.checkWin(board.returnBoard())` which should theoretically set `winner` equal to `y`, `r`, `draw` or `None`. If `winner` is not `None` then I want the game to display a banner for who wins, but currently this is not working.

If I put

```
if (rules.checkWin(board.returnBoard() != None):
   run = False
```

within the while loop in the first code segment (`run` is the bool condition for the game's while loop to keep running) then the program closes when a decisive result is reached, which is a start. However, when I try to use the methods I made to instead make the program display a message when a result is reached, nothing shows up. I'm not sure if it's because the `winner` variable isn't updated through the `getWinner` method or if the blit in `showWinner` isn't working.
Code for reference:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from c4board import *
from c4rules import *

pygame.init()

width = 700
height = 600
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
screen= pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Connect 4")

yellow = (255, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)

run = True
clicked = False
pos = []
player = "y"
winner = None

board = c4board()
rules = c4rules()

def drawBoard():
    background_color = (255, 255, 255)
    line_col = (0, 0, 0)
    screen.fill(background_color)
    for col in range(0, 7):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, line_col, (col * 100, 0), (col * 100, height), 2)
    for row in range(0, 6):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, line_col, (0, row * 100), (width, row * 100), 2)

def dropPieces():
    temp = board.returnBoard()
    for r in range(len(temp)):
        for c in range(len(temp[r])):
            if (temp[r][c] == "y"):
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, yellow, (c * 100 + 50, r * 100 + 50), 38, 0)
            if (temp[r][c] == "r"):
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (c * 100 + 50, r * 100 + 50), 38, 0)

def showWinner():
    result = ""
    if (winner == "draw"):
        result = "Draw!"
    if (winner == "y"):
        result = "Yellow Pieces Win!"
    if (winner == "r"):
        result = "Red Pieces Win!"
    result_img = font.render(result, True, green)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (width // 2 - 180, height // 2 - 135, 200, 50))
    screen.blit(result_img, (width // 2 - 180, height // 2 - 135))

while (run):

    drawBoard()
    dropPieces()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            run = False
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and clicked == False):
            clicked = True
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and clicked == True):
            clicked = False
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            col = pos[0] // 100
            if (board.freeCol(col) == True):
                board.playerMove(player, col)
                if (player == "y"):
                    player = "r"
                else:
                    player = "y"
            winner = rules.checkWin(board.returnBoard())
            showWinner()
            
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

```
import pygame

#c4board class
class c4board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                      [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                      [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                      [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                      [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                      [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],]
        
    def returnBoard(self):
        return self.board
        
    def playerMove(self, player, col):
        valid = False
        if (self.freeCol(col) == True):
            while (valid == False):
                first = True
                for r in reversed(range(len(self.board))):
                    if (self.board[r][col] == None):
                        if (first == True):
                            self.board[r][col] = player
                            first = False
                            valid = True
        return
    
    def freeCol(self, col): #checks if column is full
        if (self.board[0][col] != None):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

```
import pygame
#c4rules class
class c4rules:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def checkWin(self, board):
        full_board = True
        winner = None
        switched = [[None]*6 for _ in range(7)]
        for r in range(len(switched)): # flips board sideways to check if columns are 3 in a row
            for c in range(len(switched[r])):
                switched[r][c] = board[c][r]

        for row in range(len(board)):
            for item in board[row]:
                if (item == None):
                    full_board = False
                    
        for x1 in range(len(board)):
            if (self.across_win(board[x1]) != None):
                winner = self.across_win(board[x1])
                return winner
            for y1 in range(len(board[x1])):
                if (self.diag_win(board, x1, y1) != None):
                    winner = self.diag_win(board, x1, y1)
                    return winner
        for x2 in range(len(switched)):
            if (self.across_win(switched[x2]) != None):
                winner = self.across_win(switched[x2])
                return winner
            
        if (full_board == True and winner == None):
            return "draw"
        
        return None
        


    def across_win(self, row, counter = 0, winner = ""):
        if (counter == 4):
            return winner
        elif (len(row) == 0):
            return None
        elif (counter == 0):
            if (row[0] != None):
                winner = row[0]
                counter = counter + 1
            return self.across_win(row[1 : len(row)], counter, winner)
        else:
            if (row[0] == winner):
                counter = counter + 1
                return self.across_win(row[1 : len(row)], counter, winner)
            else:
                if (row[0] != None):
                    return self.across_win(row[1 : len(row)], counter = 1, winner = row[0])
                else:
                    return self.across_win(row[1 : len(row)], counter = 0, winner = "")

    def diag_win(self, board, r, c):
        if (r < 3 and c < 4):
            if (board[r][c] != None):
                if (board[r][c] == board[r + 1][c + 1] == board[r + 2][c + 2] == board[r + 3][c + 3]):
                        return str(board[r][c])
        if (r < 3 and c > 2):
            if (board[r][c] != None):
                if (board[r][c] == board[r + 1][c - 1] == board[r + 2][c - 2] == board[r + 3][c - 3]):
                    return str(board[r][c])
        return None
```

Comment: You check if `gameEnd` is true in `showWinner` but you only set it to `False` at the beginning and don't change it anywhere later.

Comment: @Michael Butscher Thanks for pointing that out. I deleted it but the code still isn't working

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the shown code. (2) Explain "isn't working". What happens? Show an error message (if any) completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher 1) Fixed indentations, 2) The problem is the game does output what it should after a result is reached. I want to set `winner` to the output of `checkWin` which returns `win`, `draw`, `loss` or `None`. I try to do this w/ `getWinner` function. If `winner != None` then I want Pygame to display a message box with the result (Red wins, yellow wins, or draw). Problem is 'checkWin' is working correctly and outputting the right things (tested it with sample boards) but `winner` is not updating and is still equal to `None`, so no banner pops up when a decisive result is reached

Comment: If a variable is set anywhere in a function, it is seen as local to the function (even if a global variable of same name exists) if not declared as `global`. At the beginning of method `checkWin` add line `global winner`.